# Azure Traffic Manager with my own SSL cert?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been using Azure to host my Web Apps for a while now and they've had my own wildcard cert attached to various ones with no problem. Recently, however, one of my clients has wanted a certain degree of uptime/performance (not that there have been any problems so far but they are willing to pay for it and who am I to turn down money) so I've set up mirrored sites and am using traffic manager to route between them.

It works like a charm but for one problem: I have a cname pointing a friendly url to the traffic manager address and, if I try to connect via https, it craps out and wants to use its own *.azurewebsites.com cert no matter what I try.
So my question is: am I missing something here? How to I use my own custom *.mycompany.com cert in this case?

Or, for that matter, is there a better way of doing what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish here?

Here is my set up:

Endpoint 1: MyWebApp-East (type - Azure Endpoint, ssl installed and proper host info added)
Endpoint 2: MyWebApp-West (type - Azure Endpoint, ssl installed and proper host info added)

Traffic Manager: Routing Type - Performance

**UPDATE**

Oddly enough, I got it to work. I must have had something wrong somewhere. I did a scorched earth approach to it by deleting EVERYTHING (sites, traffic manager, dns entries, etc) and starting over. It works perfectly now!

Comment: Seems like you have setup it up correctly.  It should do it for you automatically, but is trafficmanager.net listed as a domain name on the Azure web app (along with the custom domain)?

Comment: Yep.Just double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this in the top part but so as not to leave this open, I'll repost the solution I found:

Oddly enough, I got it to work. I must have had something wrong somewhere. I did a scorched earth approach to it by deleting EVERYTHING (sites, traffic manager, dns entries, etc) and starting over. It works perfectly now.

Sometimes to go forwards, you have to destroy everything.